Python app stuck on deployment to Azure App Service via GitHub Actions
I ran into an issue deploying a Python fastAPI server to an Azure App Service via GitHub Actions. I linked the code to a repository and then set up the CI pipeline to execute a deployment on new commits. The issue is that it never finishes deploying, seems to be stuck on the "deploy" task (waited 30+ min).
Furthermore, it works fine locally. The GitHub Actions setup was done on Azure Portal with the default deployment profile (shown below).
What could be the issue?
I have the following environment variables:
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT = 1

Here is an example server code:
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"message": "Hello World!"}

This is the content of requirements.txt:
fastapi==0.108.0
uvicorn==0.25.0

The app is started via a run.sh script:
uvicorn app:app

And this is the default deployment profile generated from the Deployment Center on Azure Portal:
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions
# More info on Python, GitHub Actions, and Azure App Service: https://aka.ms/python-webapps-actions

name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - test-app

on:

  push:

    branches:

      - main

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:

  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:

      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Python version

        uses: actions/setup-python@v1

        with:

          python-version: '3.10'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment

        run: |

          python -m venv venv

          source venv/bin/activate

      

      - name: Install dependencies

        run: pip install -r requirements.txt

        

      # Optional: Add step to run tests here (PyTest, Django test suites, etc.)

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment

        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs

        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3

        with:

          name: python-app

          path: |

            release.zip

            !venv/

  deploy:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    needs: build

    environment:

      name: 'Production'

      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    permissions:

      id-token: write #This is required for requesting the JWT

    steps:

      - name: Download artifact from build job

        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3

        with:

          name: python-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment

        run: unzip release.zip

      

      - name: Login to Azure

        uses: azure/login@v1

        with:

          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_CLIENTID_CBD8C3026E1A4282B849F09360374194 }}

          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_TENANTID_A6EA60031331436B85135D7D38DEA5C0 }}

          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_SUBSCRIPTIONID_342877BC8990412AAE8316D6F51A7355 }}

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'

        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2

        id: deploy-to-webapp

        with:

          app-name: 'test-app'

          slot-name: 'Production'

      


I tried your code, and it successfully deployed to the Azure App Service through GitHub Actions.
Ensure that all dependencies listed in your requirements.txt file are compatible with the Python version you are using and are successfully installed during the deployment process.
Double-check environment variables, secrets like Client Id and Client Secrets are correct and being executed during the deployment process.
Below is my complete yml file.
WorkflowFile :
name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - kafastapiapp
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.9'
      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            release.zip
            !venv/
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app
      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: 'kafastapiapp'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_<SecretKey>}}

It was successfully deployed to Azure, as shown below.

Configure the startup command below for the Azure Web App:
gunicorn --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --timeout 600 --access-logfile '-' --error-logfile '-' app:app

as shown below.

Azure App Service Output :


@John Szatmari Have you tried the solution which I have shared ?
